# How to maximize $f(x,y) = 3\sin x + 4\cos y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

Hello for an linear algebra course I have the question as seen below

2. Among all the unit vectors
   $$
   u=\left(\begin{array}{l}
   u_{1} \\
   u_{2} \\
   u_{3} \\
   u_{4}
   \end{array}\right) \in \mathbb{R}^{4}
   $$
   find the one for which the sum
   $$
   3 u_{1}-2 u_{2}+4 u_{3}-u_{4}
   $$
   is maximal.

To maximize the sum of the unit vector I have set $u_2$ and $u_4$ to $0$ since they do not contribute to the sum. Then we are left with $2$ variables that squared have to add up to $1$. Thats when I thought of the unit circle since that always adds up to one. But trigonometry is not my strongest point and I am now trying to figure out how to maximize $3\sin x + 4\cos y$ since this would be a valid unit vector and maximize the sum in the question. Or is there another way to answer this questions. Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Thomas

Comment: Do you know Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: $u_2,u_4$ could be negative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u$ is a unit vector means $||u|| = \sqrt{u_1^2 +u_2^2 + u_3^2 + u_4^2} = 1$. Consider it as a constraint on the vector you seek $u$ in the form
$$
g(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4) = 0\qquad {\rm i.e. } \qquad \sqrt{u_1^2 +u_2^2 + u_3^2 + u_4^2} - 1 =0
$$
the function you have $f(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4) = 3u_1 - 2u_2 + 4u_3-u_4$ must be maximized subject to the cnstraint above.

using Lagrange multipliers methode you get the system
$$
\nabla f(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4)\ - \lambda \nabla g(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4) = \vec{0} \\
g(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4) = 0
$$
Solve for $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$ and $\lambda$ you get two solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've had Lagrange multipliers but this was last year and I kind of forgot about it. This is indeed the correct way and I will look into Lagrange multipliers again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are given the vector ${\bf a}:=(3,-2,4,-1)$ and are looking for the unit vector ${\bf u}\in{\mathbb R}^4$ for which the scalar product
$${\bf a}\cdot{\bf u}$$
is maximal. By Schwarz' inequality we have ${\bf a}\cdot{\bf u}\leq|{\bf a}|$ for all ${\bf u}\in S^3$. Maybe you find a ${\bf u}\in S^3$ for which we equality here.

Comment: As a follow-up, remember that the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality states that there is an equality if and only if  and  are scalar multiples of each other.